# Why Are List Items Left Behind using JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML markup,

```
<ul>
    <li id="inspectionItem">blah</li>
    <li id="inspectionItem">blah</li>
</ul>
```

When I do this in jQuery,

```
$("#inspectionItem").remove();
```

It only removes the first item from the list and we are left with this,

```
<ul>
    <li id="inspectionItem">blah</li>
</ul>
```

I thought the idea of the selector I have used is that it would select all of the list items that matched?

I am just learning jquery, so I am not too familiar with the cause. Does anybody have any debugging tips for something like this?

Comment: try using class="inspectionItem" instead of id. And then do : $(".inspectionItem").remove(); .. does it work?

Comment: Any decent html editor would be complaining about the multiple identical Id field.

Comment: here u go, @Rob Hruska said it seconds before me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id` attributes should be unique throughout the document. Since you've got multiple elements with the same `id`, the behavior will be unpredictable.

I'd suggest changing them to classes, e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li class="inspectionItem">blah</li>
    <li class="inspectionItem">blah</li>
</ul>
```

With

```
$(".inspectionItem").remove();
```

Comment: Yeah as you can see I am just learning. Does that class that you are specifying have to be in the CSS, I guess not.

Comment: @peter - `class`es can be used for a number of things beyond CSS styling. No problem that you're learning, you've come to the right place. :)